# Kohana 3.3: WHERE statement with relationships

Tags: php, kohana

I have setup Kohana models with relationships define (1:* and *:* using `through`) but wanted to know the best way to use them in `WHERE` statements.

Example: I have a `User` model and a `Post` model. `Post` has a foreign key (`userID`) to `User`

I have setup a `$_has_many` relationship on the `User` model with an alias `user_created`

I know I can use the actual field `userID`, but I want to be able to do something like this

```
$user->where('user_created', 'IS', NULL);
```

This would also be handy for checking whether a many-to-many with something like this

```
'm2m_relation_count', '>', 0
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the ORM in Kohana in the following way.

```
$user->user_created->find_all();
```

This will result in all Posts the User created.

If you want to check if the User has created posts you just use the same function and do a `count()` on the result and check if it is greater than 0.

I don't think you can use the alias in a `where` clause itself. You have to call it from the ORM object.

Many-to-many relations work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no quick method to get all users without posts. Id prefer to add special column `post_count` and increment it after posting.

2) You can check user for m:m relationship with `has()`/`has_any()` methods:

```
if ($user->has('roles')) { 
    // user has at least one role
}

if ($user->has('roles', $roleId) {
    // user has role with id=$roleId
}

if ($user->has('roles', array($roleId1, $roleId2))) {
    // user has both $roleId and $roleId2 roles
}

if ($user->has_any('roles', array($roleId1, $roleId2))) {
    // user has on of the $roleId1 or $roleId2
}
```